# Wordpress title-tag function

Tags: wordpress-theming

need help..
I'm learning to build a wordpress theme by own self and i'll change separator `-`to `|` if use function`add_theme_support( ‘title-tag’ );`. as far as I know it can be if use `wp_title()`function.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 4.1, developers are discouraged to use `wp_title()` function. So you should ignore that part for now.

For changing separator using `title-tag` you can use the following filter:

```
add_filter('document_title_separator', 'my_custom_separator');
function my_custom_separator($sep){
    $sep = '-';
    return $sep;
}
```